# Column with array with all months in x amount of years from starting date - Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, date, pyspark

Imagine you have a dataframe df as follows:

```
ID  Years     Date
A    5    2021-02-01
B    3    2021-02-01
C    6    2021-02-01
```

I want to be able to create an additional date array column with all the dates starting from the initial date + 1 month all the way to the x amount of years in the years column. It would look like the following:

```
ID  Years     Date        Dates
A    5    2021-02-01     [2021-03-01,2021-04-01,...,2026-02-01]
B    3    2021-03-01     [2021-04-01,2021-04-01,...,2024-03-01]
C    6    2021-02-01     [2021-03-01,2021-04-01,...,2027-02-01]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share it with us, please?

Comment: I have a very ugly pandas implementation, where I'm using iterrows() and then multiply the number of years by 12 and then add one month to the date in a second loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For spark >= 2.4, you can use the `sequence` and `add_months` functions to generate the desired sequence of dates.

```
df = df.withColumn('Dates',
                   F.expr('sequence(add_months(to_date(Date), 1), add_months(to_date(Date), int(Years) * 12), interval 1 month)')
                   )
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert in PySpark, and I heard that changing PySpark to a pandas dataframe could not be interesting in some cases. But if it's ok, you can change the format to pandas and try using `apply` function:

```py
df = df_spark.toPandas()
def getRangeDate(row):
  return list(map(lambda x: x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), list(pd.date_range(start = row["Date"], periods = 12*row["Years"]+1, freq = 'MS'))[1:]))
df['Dates'] = df.apply(getRangeDate, axis=1)
df
```

which, regarding your example input, has the following output:

```
    ID  Years   Date    Dates
0   A   5   2021-02-01  [2021-03-01, 2021-04-01, 2021-05-01, ..., 2026-02-01]
1   B   3   2021-03-01  [2021-04-01, 2021-05-01, 2021-06-01, ..., 2024-03-01]
2   C   6   2021-02-01  [2021-03-01, 2021-04-01, 2021-05-01, ..., 2027-02-01]
```

Comment: I don't think this is pyspark but pandas dataframes ...

Comment: @AntonioLópezRuiz Yes, you are right. I didn't notice that you are using PySpark. Anyway, I edited to answer as per your comment.

Comment: Converting to pandas is not what I am looking for, I want it to be preserved as a spark dframe.